# How to reset AuthorizationHeader from HttpClientFactory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, httpclient, httpclientfactory

I'm developing a Blazor App which consumes three different APIs, and everything is going fine until the API token expires.

My problem is about having the token with the HTTPClientFactory. Right now, I'm using this approach but feel free to tell me I'm completely wrong about it

```
services.AddHttpClient("first-api", options =>
        {
            options.BaseAddress = new Uri(first_api_uri);
        });
```

First, I inject the HttpClient for any of the APIs. Let´s say it´s the first one.
After that, I configure the HttpClientFactory to my APIService and set the Default Header (bearer token) reading from my Protected Local Storage.

```
services.AddScoped<IAPIOneService, APIOneService>(context =>
        {
            var httpClientFactory = context.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
            var httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("first-api");
            var storage = context.GetRequiredService<ProtectedLocalStorage>();
            AddHeader(httpClient, storage);
            var apiClient = new APIClient(httpClient);
            return new APIOneService(apiClient);
        });
```

As I said before, the AddHeader set the Authorization Header to the HttpClient, which goes inside of a "handler" of requests (built by me), called APIClient.
If the token expires, I get a 401 from the server and send the user to the login page, but, when it logs in again, the HttpClient keeps the old token, probably because it does not pass through the DI section where the AddHeader writes the new Authentication Header.

I'm probably doing it wrong, but writing a HttpMessageHandler just does not work because AddHeader cannot read from my Protected Local Storage. It's something from Blazor rules.

Can someone help me and give me the right way to do it?

Comment: How do you generate the token?

Comment: The token is already in the protected local storage

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom TokenRefreshHandler and add it to the HttpClient pipeline. The handler could check the response status code for each request and determine if it is a 401 Unauthorized error. If so, it can refresh the token and add this new token to the header before re-sending the request.

**TokenRefreshHandler.cs**

```
public class TokenRefreshHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly ProtectedLocalStorage _protectedLocalStorage;

    public TokenRefreshHandler(ProtectedLocalStorage protectedLocalStorage)
    {
        _protectedLocalStorage = protectedLocalStorage;
    }

    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        {
            // Refresh the token
            string newToken = await RefreshToken();
            _protectedLocalStorage.Set("token", newToken);

            // Add the new token to the header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", newToken);

            // Re-send the request with the new token
            response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        return response;
    }

    private async Task<string> RefreshToken()
    {
        // Refresh the token and return the new token value
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Register**

```
    services.AddHttpClient("first-api", options =>
    {
        options.BaseAddress = new Uri(first_api_uri);
    })
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenRefreshHandler>();
```

Comment: It's looks like the same to me. The refreshtoken will get the protected storage error (JS cannot run at this time), but I'll give it a try, thanks!